# Xamarin.forms Rg.Plugins.Popup background page blur

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms application which uses **Rg.Plugins.popup** for showing custom popup.Everything works fine. But is there any workaround for making the background page blur when the popup is shown?Thanks in advance

**What I have done**
[image]

**What I would like to obtain**[image]

Comment: Blur in what sense,I am pretty sure it makes your background page transparent!

Comment: @G.hakim Bro I edited my question.Please check

Comment: maybe add the relevant code i have a feeling you are missing something here

Comment: @G.hakim Bro I dont know what will be it. :(

Comment: Well have you push the pop up and how did you setup RG pop-up would do i guess

Comment: That would be a bad work around but whatever suits you

Comment: You could add a custom Blur background behind the pop up and remove it when the pop up dismiss.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Thats what actually I done. But how can I get exact blur of behind screen?

Comment: You want to know how to create a blur pop up?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT No , Not Blur popup. Blur background , like I shown in the pic. :)

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I tried it using blurred screenshot of the page behind of pop up and set it as background image for popup.It looked nearly neat in android. but in ios it looked not that good

Comment: Ok, let me do some research and I will let you know if I find anything.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Thanks bro......

Answer (score 3):

I made nuget package for this. Use for Xamarin.Forms - working in android and ios with smoothly appearing animation. Required Xamarin.Forms >= 4.0.

[image]

Check it: [PrettyPopup](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ascetic.Plugins.PrettyPopup/1.2.0)

Comment: @AndroDevil, package is updated to 1.2.1 version. Now you can customize your blur effect. I will be glad to reviews)

Comment: How to init this package? I tried like this  AsceticAscetic.Plugins.PopupDecorations.<Droid/iOS>.PrettyPopup.Init()

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:

You can create a blur background by using `visualelement-blur` on iOS. You can have a look at this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/visualelement-blur).

Here I write a simple method to explain:

```
 void showBlurBackGround()
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {
            // change the width and height to your own requirement
            var boxView = new BoxView { HeightRequest = 300, WidthRequest = 350 };
            boxView.On<iOS>().UseBlurEffect(BlurEffectStyle.ExtraLight);
            myLaout.Children.Add(boxView);
        }
        else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            // add your image
        }           
    }
```

I'm not familiar with Android maybe you can find a better solution instead of add a blurred screenshot. You can try creating some bitmaps and blurring them.

Comment: Ok let me check this bro.

Comment: @AndroDevil Do you get success?

Comment: @ Jack Hua  No bro..Do you got anything for android?

Comment: What's your problem? Did  boxView.On<iOS().UseBlurEffect(BlurEffectStyle.ExtraLight);
 work for you?

Comment: Bro I know this will work for ios..But I want a solution for android too...Thats the issue ;(

Comment: @AndroDevil Have a look at the sample maybe helps. You need a create a custom render view in Android. [Xamarin.BlurView](https://github.com/wcoder/Xamarin.BlurView)

Comment: Ok bro let me check it